# Maximum of a function $ f(t)= at+b \sqrt{1-t^2}$

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

Let $ a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $ f(t)= at+b \sqrt{1-t^2}$ for $t \in [-1,1]$. How do we find the maximum value of $f(t)$ on this range?

Comment: What do you mean by "the derivative did not come out"? It should be a relatively straightforward computation...keep in mind that $a,b$ are constants.

Comment: A standard textbook method is to first find extremal points in the interior of the domain. Solve $f'(t) = 0$ and if this has solutions $t_i$ in $(-1,1)$ (as it has here) then there is a local maximum/minimum at those points. Then compare the value at these local extremal points, $f(t_i)$, with the value at the boundary, i.e. $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$. The maximum of all these points is the maximum you are after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By C-S $$at+b\sqrt{1-t^2}\leq\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(t^2+1-t^2)}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$
The equality occurs for $(a,b)||(t,\sqrt{1-t^2})$

Comment: Is $ \sqrt{a^2+b^2} $ necessarily the maximum of the function?

Comment: @mathuser81124 Yes, I think so. Because the equality always occurs.

Answer (score 0):

An idea:
$t=sinx$, $f\circ sin=g$

Now we have: $$g(x)=asinx+bcosx,\ x\in(-\pi,\pi)$$

$$g'(x)=acosx-bsinx\\
g'(x)=0 <=>acosx=bsinx <=> tgx=\frac{a}{b} <=> x=arctg\frac{a}{b}$$

$t=sin(arctg\frac{a}{b})$

The problem is that the way this function will behave highly depends on a and b. You can't solve well this problem unless you know more about a  and b.